# Replace radiator

Tags: ac, cooling-system, radiator, condenser

In changing a radiator in a 2005 GMC Canyon with a 3.5, 2 wheel drive. Can I get the radiator out without opening any lines on the AC unit. Can I get the AC condenser off the radiator without opening the freon lines.

Comment: The simple answer is: Yes. https://youtu.be/J0gL3Y0nHLU